# Chrome: Add to homescreen error: Site cannot be installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Board",
  "short_name": "Board",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "public/sw-Board-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "any",
  "background_color": "#303030",
  "theme_color": "#212121",
  "description": "SLA Monitoring Tool",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "en-US"
}
```

Service Worker Registration

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(`Board/service-worker.js`)
```

I'm running my app on Local IIS so my app runs from http://localhost/Board

This seems to work as the application tab in Chrome is showing Manifest file info and also shows the service-worker being installed.

However, when I click on the "Add to homescreen" link from the Application > Manifest tab I get the following error:

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may
>   need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the
>   current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

I'm not sure what's going on, but when I didn't have this problem when developing a node express backed pwa.

I'm trying to adjust the `start_url` and `scope` properties in the manifest.json but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Google codelab [Add Your Web App to a User's Home Screen](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#0) that you can follow.

You can also check the [Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) and the new [The New and Improved Add to Home screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen).

Answer (score 0):

The browser will call `beforeinstallprompt` only when the service worker goes into effect with no errors thrown.

And the create react app service worker will only go into effect in production, so build it and serve it locally, then try to "Add to Homescreen".

Install serve npm first, if it isn't already: `npm i serve -g`

Then...

`npm run build`

`serve -s build`